# Using Atmosphere and GWT without maven

Tags: gwt, atmosphere

I'm trying to use the atmosphere framework with GWT, so I added the runtime and the three GWT20 jars, but when I run I get the following error...

com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) @org.atmosphere.gwt20.client.Atmosphere::subscribeImpl(Lorg/atmosphere/gwt20/client/AtmosphereRequestConfig;)([JavaScript object(1403)]): this.subscribe is not a function

Does anyone know what this means and how I can go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out, to get the demo working for GWT20 under the atmosphere extensions, you need to manually create the javascript folder with the atmosphere.js in it and also the META-INF/atmosphere.xml from the demo. Both of these folders in the WAR folder.

Here's a link to the working [demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5FF_Ld8SzsNOURLM0hkTUZHNzA/edit?usp=sharing)